# Not able to loop through Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to use Autocomplete from Angular Material but fail with an error.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="currencies$ | async as currencies">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Currency</mat-label>
    <input id="currency" type="text" matInput placeholder="Select a currency. E.g. USD" [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let currency of currencies | keyvalue" [value]="currency.key">
        {{currency.key}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

I get this error on `currencies` (within `*ngFor="let c of currencies | keyvalue"`):

> Argument type ObservedValueOf<Observable<{[p: string]: string}>> is
> not assignable to parameter type ReadonlyMap<unknown, unknown>

**Service**

```js
list(): Observable<Currencies> {
  return this._http.get<Currencies>('./assets/currencies.json');
}
```

**Type**

```js
export type Currencies = Record<string, string>;
```

**Component**

```js
currencies$ = this._currencyService.list().pipe(
  switchMap((currencies) => {
    return this.formMain.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((query) =>
        Object.fromEntries(
          Object.entries(currencies).filter(([key]) =>
            key.includes(query.toUpperCase())
          )
        )
      )
    );
  })
);
```

So `currencies$` returns *Observable<{[p: string]: string}>*. That explains the error but how can I fix it?

---

I have also tried it with `*ngFor="let currency of currencies$ | keyvalue"`. Then the error is gone but the values of `currency.key` are *operator* and *source* which is wrong.

Comment: have you tried using an async pipe?

Comment: @TobiasS. yes, see the answer below. But I still get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `async` pipe and `keyvalue` pipe together as shown below

```
<ng-container *ngIf="currencies$ | async">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Currency</mat-label>
    <input id="currency" type="text" matInput placeholder="Select a currency. E.g. USD" [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let currency of currencies$| async | keyvalue" [value]="currency.key">
        {{currency.key}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Now I get this error: _Argument type ObservedValueOf<Observable<{[p: string]: string}>> | null is not assignable to parameter type ReadonlyMap<unknown, unknown>_

Comment: See the updated answer. If that does not fix issue, create a StackBlitz reproduction.

Comment: I still get an error. On StackBlitz it works fine but I still get an error in my application. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q9ms62-hzcddo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.html